# Download Images from server location saved in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-asynctask

I am developing a android application. In one activity I have to download multiple images associated with a List Item say 2 images per List Item. The Image URLs are saved in Sqlite DB. These images are LowRes and HighRes Images. I have to download them when I first launch the application. I have also set boolean flag (with each IMAGE URL )in DB to check whether the image has been downloaded or not. If not fetch them else proceed to next URL. If image is fetched successfully, I have to save in storage and mark the corresponding flag as true so that I can directly search folder for the file. My understanding is:
1. Go through the DB file and find the items(rows) whose downloaded flag is false.
2. Gather all these URLs and send these to AsyncTask to download them.
My Sample DB structure:

| ItemName | LowResImageURL| HighResImageURL | LowResDownloaded | HighResDownloaded|

Query: 
1. Once a image is downloaded, how can I get the reference of corresponding flag in DB so that I can set it as 'True' i.e.How to get/pass row reference to my ImageDownload method?
2. Best way to download approx 300 images from server.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is coming to my mind is that I have to create a class to store the values from the DB then pass the object to async task, update the object accordingly after the image is downloaded and saved. After its done, update the DB from the updated class object.